# Please explain what is happening with this 2 lines of bash code

Tags: bash

im trying to learn bash right now, came across a script and im not 100% sure if i read it right.

```
source_dir_123=${SOURCE_DIR:-/tmp}
echo source_dir_123=$source_dir_123
```

What is happening here? I guess this is some kinda variable assigment, but it looks weird to me.
What type of assigment/operation happens here? Any specific name of these types of assignments?
Sorry for a newbish question, but i dont get it why would you use these kinda of                               assignments instead of something more straight forward like

```
source_dir_12="/tmp"
```

Comment: `echo source_dir_123=$source_dir_123` simply outputs `source_dir_123=` followed by whatever is stored in that variable. If it did not already have a value, then `/tmp` will be stored there, thus the full output  would be `source_dir_123=/tmp`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/tmp` is the default value for `source_dir_123` in case `SOURCE_DIR` is not set, then you're displaying the result to the console.

See the following example:

```sh
> echo $SOURCE_DIR

> source_dir_123=${SOURCE_DIR:-/tmp}
> echo source_dir_123=$source_dir_123
source_dir_123=/tmp
# now let's set SOURCE_DIR
> SOURCE_DIR=/test
> source_dir_123=${SOURCE_DIR:-/tmp}
> echo source_dir_123=$source_dir_123
source_dir_123=/test
```

Comment: Thank you! Bash is very powerful,but sometimes can be a bit confusing  :)